# How to get ROW_NUMBER to start over (reset) after ROW_NUMBER reaches a certain number

Tags: sql

I need my ROW_NUMBER column to start over if it counts up to three per taskName. There can be multiple amounts of tasks with the same name so if there are over three tasks with the same name I need the ROW_NUMBER column to start over.

My code below only gets my ROW_NUMBER column to reset after a new task name is present, however, I need it to do that and reset the ROW_NUMBER column back to one if the number gets up to three and another task with the same name still exists.

```
SELECT t.[taskId], tq.name as taskName, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tq.name 
    ORDER BY tq.name) AS RowNum 
FROM Task t (NOLOCK)
order by tq.name asc
```

Current Results:

```
taskID  taskName  RowNum
1       Name1     1
2       Name1     2
3       Name1     3
4       Name1     4
5       Name1     5
6       Name1     6
8       Name2     1
8       Name2     2
```

Expected Results:

```
taskID  taskName  RowNum
1       Name1     1
2       Name1     2
3       Name1     3
4       Name1     1
5       Name1     2
6       Name1     3
8       Name2     1
8       Name2     2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use modulo arithmetic:

```
SELECT t.[taskId], tq.name as taskName, 
       1 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tq.name ORDER BY tq.name) - 1) % 3 AS RowNum_3 
FROM Task t 
ORDER BY tq.name asc;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the quick response!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the database is MSSQL:

```
SELECT t.[taskId], tq.name as taskName,    
CASE 
    WHEN (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tq.name ORDER BY tq.name))%3 = 0 THEN 3 
    ELSE (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY tq.name ORDER BY tq.name))%3 
END AS RowNum 
FROM Task t (NOLOCK)
```